# From list getting keys and values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, matplotlib

I have problem with making dictionary and getting a keys and values from my list of names and values.

The list looks like this:

```
['smer', '1245', 'kdh', '7845', 'smer', '697', 'sns', '78', 'du', '421', 'smer', '632', 'ol', '4144', 'most-hid', '457', 'smer', '12', 'ol', '897', 'most-hid', '1234', 'kdh', '555', 'ol', '898', 'du', '7845']
```

My question is how I get the names as key and the numbers as value.

And if the key is already in dictionary it will sum the those values together.

Then how I make a Pie graph from it.

I am just learning python and I can't figure this one out.

```
def strany():
slovnik={}
zoznam=[]
x=open('Strany.txt','r')
for i in x.readlines():
    i=i.strip()
    casty=i.split(' ')
    for x in casty:
        zoznam.append(x)
```

I don't how to continue

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: What have you tried?  What specifically isn't working?  What errors are you getting?  What does your code look like?

Comment: Don't build the list in the first place. It's much easier to build the dict directly from the file. When you build the list, you lose the natural grouping into pairs that the file gives you.

Comment: @user2357112, that won't work for repeating keys

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Right, just saw that part. It's still easier to build the dict directly, though; it's just not a one-liner any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) summing the values for repeated keys, call `ite`r on the list and unpack each pairing in a loop after zipping:

```
l = ['smer', '1245', 'kdh', '7845', 'smer', '697', 'sns', '78', 'du', '421', 'smer', '632', 'ol', '4144', 'most-hid', '457', 'smer', '12', 'ol', '897', 'most-hid', '1234', 'kdh', '555', 'ol', '898', 'du', '7845']

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
it = iter(l)
for k,v in zip(it,it):
    d[k] += int(v)

print(d) 
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'sns': 78, 'ol': 5939, 'du': 8266, 'smer': 2586, 'most-hid': 1691, 'kdh': 8400})
```

If you pairings are coming from the file just unpack as you go using the csv lib to parse the file presuming your data is delimited by whitesapce:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

with open("infile") as f:
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for k,v in csv.reader(f,delimiter=" "):
        d[k] += int(v)

print(d)
```

You could achieve the same using a regular dict and `dict.setdefault`:

```
with open("infile") as f:
    d = {}
    for k,v in csv.reader(f,delimiter=" "):
        d.setdefault(k , 0)
        d[k] += int(v)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate through the list, stepping by two, and grabbing each key/value out. Like so

```
l = ['1','a','2','b','3','c']
for i in range(0, len(l), 2):
    print('key=' + l[i] + 'value=' + l[i+1])
```

Replace the print function with whatever suits your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

summed = {}
x = ['smer', '1245', 'kdh', '7845', 'smer', '697', 'sns', '78', 'du', '421', 'smer', '632', 'ol', '4144', 'most-hid', '457', 'smer', '12', 'ol', '897', 'most-hid', '1234', 'kdh', '555', 'ol', '898', 'du', '7845']
it = iter(x)
for k,v in zip(it,it):
    summed[k] = summed.get(k,0) + float(v)

plt.pie(summed.values(), labels=summed.keys())
plt.show()
```

And to handle the file part, assuming you want a single pie graph across all lines in the file:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('Strany.txt') as f:
    it = (y for z in f for y in z.strip().split())

summed = {}
for k,v in zip(it,it):
    summed[k] = summed.get(k,0) + float(v)

plt.pie(summed.values(), labels=summed.keys())
plt.show()
```

Comment: Read the question first.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an iterator from the list and use it's `next` method

```
lt_iter= iter(lst)
dic={}
while True:
    try:
        key=lt_iter.next()
        value= lt_iter.next()
        if key in dic:
            dic[key]+=value
        else:
            dic[key]=value
    except StopIteration:
        break

print dic
```

Answer (score 0):

The loading to a dictionary is easy but you'll need a plotting library like [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/index.html) to generate the pie chart.

```
#load the value in the list
k = ['smer', '1245', 'kdh', '7845', 'smer', '697', 'sns', '78', 'du', '421', 'smer', '632', 'ol', '4144', 'most-hid', '457', 'smer', '12', 'ol', '897', 'most-hid', '1234', 'kdh', '555', 'ol', '898', 'du', '7845']

#create a dictionary to hold the values
d = {}

for i in range(0,len(k),2):#iterate the length of the list, i will be every other index
    key = k[i]
    val = float(k[i+1])
    if d.has_key(key): #if the key exists perform summation
        d[key] += val
    else: #if the key does not exist create it
        d[key] = val

# a plotting library like matplot lib is required for the pie chart
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
labels = d.keys()
values = d.values()

plt.pie(values,              # data
        labels=labels,      # slice labels
        autopct='%1.1f%%',  # print the values inside the wedges
        )

plt.show()
```

Answer (score -2):

statistics.sk is getting ready for elections? muhehehe

```
result = {}
a=['smer', '8', 'kdh', '7', 'smer', '6']
while a:
    party = a.pop(0)
    number = int(a.pop(0))
    if (party in result.keys()):
        result[party]+=number
    else:
        result[party]=number
```

Comment: Unfortunately yes but it is bonus homework assignment so I was trying to do but now I am in hurry

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham you're 100% right. Your answer is real python mine is 'python for dummies' (no offense).

Comment: I don't want to offend, but this shouldn't be the winner.  There are much better answers below